# Alter Table Set unique error on postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, alter-table

I am using Postgres as DBMS and Django.

My model that defines the table is:

```
class TtnetModem(models.Model):
    ttnetModemSerino=models.CharField(_(u"Seri No"), max_length=20, default='', null=True, blank=True)
```

I change field definition...

```
ttnetModemSerino=models.CharField(_(u"Seri No"), max_length=20, unique= True)
```

on postgres, i execute :

```
ALTER TABLE bayiislemleri_ttnetmodem ADD CONSTRAINT ttnetModemSerino_key UNIQUE(ttnetModemSerino);
```

bayiislemleri is my application name and ttnetmodem is my model name... But i get floolwing error:

> ERROR:  column "ttnetmodemserino" named in key does not exist

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ttnetmodemserino is in lower case, it looks like ttnetModemSerino has some upper case characters. Make sure your piece of SQL uses double quotes for the objects:

```
ALTER TABLE bayiislemleri_ttnetmodem ADD CONSTRAINT ttnetModemSerino_key UNIQUE("ttnetModemSerino");
```

I have no idea how to do it in Django, can't help you there.